# Viewing Request.Form values in MVC5 project debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-debugging

I have set a break point on my action controller and added `Request.Form` to the watch list.

In the debugger I can only see the forms keys.  How can I access the values in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using either the FormCollection or a Strongly Typed Model for this? So something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection form)
{
    // Get Params
    string var1 = form["var1"];
    string var2 = form["var2"];
    // ...

    return View(form);
}
```

Or perhaps this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAction(SomeModel model)
{
    // Get Params
    string var1 = model.Property1;
    string var2 = model.Property2;
    // ...

    return View(model);
}
```